# Update related record with batch class

Tags: apex, batch, class, lookup, relationships

I'm running a batch class over the *Timesheet* object and for the timesheets that meet the criteria, I want to update the related *Contact* record.

I have a *jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c* object with a field *jstcl__Consultant__c* relating *jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c* to the *Contact* object. I'm trying to run a batch class over the timesheets and for the ones that meet the criteria, I want to update the *Previous_Timesheet_Status__c* field on the related *Contact* record. What I have now runs successfully, however it doesn't actually update the field.

```
public class batchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
      String query = 'SELECT Id, jstcl__Consultant__r.Previous_Timesheet_Status__c FROM jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c WHERE jstcl__Placement__r.ts2__Status__c =\'Active\' AND jstcl__Placement__r.VMS__c = \'\' AND jstcl__Week_Ending__c = LAST_N_DAYS:4 AND jstcl__Status__c = \'Pending\'';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c> a){
      for(jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c b : a){
         b.jstcl__Consultant__r.Previous_Timesheet_Status__c = 'Pending';
      }
    update a;
   }
   public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your update statement is updating the list of timesheet records, whereas you need it to update a list of contacts. I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
public class batchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
      String query = 'SELECT Id, jstcl__Consultant__r.Previous_Timesheet_Status__c FROM jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c WHERE jstcl__Placement__r.ts2__Status__c =\'Active\' AND jstcl__Placement__r.VMS__c = \'\' AND jstcl__Week_Ending__c = LAST_N_DAYS:4 AND jstcl__Status__c = \'Pending\'';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c> timesheets){
      List<Contact> consultants = new List<Contact>();
      for(jstcl__TG_Timesheet__c timesheet : timesheets){
         Contact consultant = timesheet.jstcl__Consultant__r;
         if (consultant == null) continue;
         consultant.Previous_Timesheet_Status__c = 'Pending';
         consultants.add(consultant);
      }
      update consultants;
   }
   public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

I took the liberty of assigning some more intuitive variable names than 'a' and 'b'; this can help other people reading your code more easily understand what it does.

Comment: N.B. SFSE etiquette is to not solicit for marking answers if it helps the questioner. See [Meta Post](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed/2128#2128) on this subject

Comment: Aah, apologies; I thought I saw that as a thing on another SE :-). Thanks for the heads-up; deleted